# How to have Windows DOSKEY alias execute another alias

Tags: windows, command-line

I have some Windows command line aliases:

```
DOSKEY ls=dir
DOSKEY up=cd ..
```

I know I can combine commands using $T

```
DOSKEY lsup=dir $T cd ..
```

But how can I create an alias to execute other aliases in my aliases.cmd file?

```
DOSKEY lsup=ls ? up
```

Comment: You can't. `doskey` does not support nested aliases.